# ComboBox did not Bind

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, data-binding

i have the object of class like

```
MYDepartment myDepartment = new MYDepartment();
```

then List defined as following

```
Ilist<MYDepartment> listDepartment=new Ilist<MYDepartment>();
```

add objects in list one by one

```
listDepartment.Add(myDepartment);
```

Now I've defined DataTable and DataRow

```
DataTable dtDepartments=new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dtDepartments.NewRow();
dr["DepartmentID"] = myDepartment.DepartmentID;
dr["Name"] = myDepartment.DepartmenrName;
dr["Description"] = myDepartment.DepartmentDescription;
dtDepartments.Rows.Add(dr);

DepartmentForm azhaform = new DepartmentForm();
azhaform.combox1.DataSource = dtDepartments;
azhaform.combobox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentID";
azhaform.combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

but it did not show ant thing in Combobox.Whats wrong with my code
please help

Answer (score 1):

Please make your DisplayMember property to `DepartmenrName`.

Like this:

```
   azhaform.combobox1.DisplayMember = "DepartmenrName";
```

Are you sure it did not show anything? It should have shown just one item, since you have added just one row to your source table.

**Edit: Sorry for the blunder I posted above. I am too used to populating with List<> :). I tried your code and it works fine. Trouble must be with something else. Please cancel my vote :)**

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't check it with my editor but it seems a little problem as I have modified it as below...

```
    DepartmentForm azhaform = new DepartmentForm();
    azhaform.combobox1.DataSource = dtDepartments;
    azhaform.combobox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentID";
    azhaform.combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be quite a few mistakes in your code, so I'm not sure if I should take it too literally (e.g. "combox1" vs "combobox1"), but the one mistake I can see immediately is that you are setting the datasource on the combobox before you have specified what the ValueMember and DisplayMember are.  I haven't tested whether this is going to cause your problem, but it definitely seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This may not what you want, but I usualy archive this using **BindingSource** component, just click on smart tag in **ComboBox** and check **Use Data Bound Items**, next click **Add Project Data Source** and select **Object** on Data Source form and choose your **MYDepartment** class.

[image: Wizard]

This will automaticaly add **BindingSource** component on your form (in my VS it named *mYDepartmentBindingSource*).

Next click again on **ComboBox** smart tag and do this :

[image: ComboBox Property]

Now you can add data :

```
  mYDepartmentBindingSource.Add(new MYDepartment() { DepartmentID=1, DepartmenrName="Abc" } );
  mYDepartmentBindingSource.Add(new MYDepartment() { DepartmentID = 2, DepartmenrName = "Bca" });
```